# What does the call operator STL USES here mean?

Tags: c++, stl, sgi

I was recently looking at the source code for SGI STL and found many places where it used call operators that I could not understand, such as:

```
typedef typename _type_traits<T1>::is_POD_type is_POD;
_uninitialized_fill_aux(first, last, v, is_POD());
```

There is a call operation at the end(is_POD()).

I know `is_POD` is a type and it is defined as follows:

```
struct _true_type{};
struct _false_type{}; 

template <class T>
struct _type_traits{ 
    ...
    ...
    typedef _false_type is_POD_type;
};
```

As I see, `is_POD` is a type but it does not overloaded the `（）` operation, so how can it call `（）`？

What does the call funtion at this place mean?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It creates an instance of the `is_POD` type using [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Comment: Oh, yes! I realized that point right now!

Comment: It is just a default construction! 
I am so stupid!